# Class 'MyApp\mysqli' not found for php5.6

Tags: php, ubuntu, mysqli

I have two php versions on my server (Ubuntu 14.04) php5.6 and php7.2

I have mysqli installed and worked before. But not, when i try to run command

```
php5.6 bin/wserver.php
```

I got an error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MyApp\mysqli' not found in
/home/server/src/MyApp/MySQL.php on line 32
```

in php.ini (php5.6) i see both extensions

```
extension=mysqlnd.so
extension=mysqli.so
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Show us the code for `wserver.php`, or just change your use of `mysqli` to `\mysqli` to use the global namespace.

Comment: Hey Jon, thanks for the answer. Will check and return in a few min

Comment: Hey Jon, \mysqli helped. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You probably are using something like this currently:

```
$db = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
```

Change it to:

```
$db = new \mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
```

Adding a preceding \ before the mysqli() function will ignore the namespace MyApp